# 'to_char' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, type-conversion, to-char

```
    (to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')+least(sign((sysdate-to_date('01-Aug-'||
to_char(sysdate,'YYYY'),'DD-Mon-RRRR'))),0)) "AcYear"
```

Error:

```
'to_char' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

I tried changing to_char and to_date to CONVERT but getting error.

I am expecting to see 2016 as AcYear

Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you sure you are using sql server?  `to_char` isn't a function in sql server.

Comment: Oracle is not SQL Server: functions vary.

Comment: What about the message do you not understand?  Why are you using an Oracle/Postgres/Teradata function in SQL Server? At the very least, you should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server if you want the first day of August, then use `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(year(getdate()), 8, 1)
```

This works in SQL Server 2012+.  Earlier versions require slightly more work:

```
select cast(datename(year, getdate()) + '0801' as date)
```